# ubuntu 16.04.1 lts login flickering

Tags: boot, 16.04, login, flicker

My ubuntu is flickering after I'm typing my password and hitting login. I can run in guest mode, it runs perfectly fine but unfortunately I can't make another usb drive from there, tried to run in recovery mode but didn't solved anything. Please help.